# Linux Bash Command - Displaying Processor Speed - Specific Lines

Tags: linux, performance, bash, cpu, processor

I am looking for the command to not only show the processor speed but display specific lines. These lines must contain "MHz" or "HZ". Would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: What is your input, what is your desired output, what have you tried?

Comment: So you're looking for `grep`?

Comment: I have used the command "lscpu" to display the CPU information. What I wish to happen is only display the lines containing either "MHz" or "Hz".

Comment: I do not have that much experience with Linux so I'm not quite certain what grep is.

Comment: Time to start reading, then! `man grep`

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart, you have solved my problem. Thank you very much and thank you to everyone else who contributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a regex.

```
grep -P 'M?Hz' /proc/cpuinfo
```

(I assume you made a a typo and meant `Hz` instead of `HZ`.)

`grep` is a tool that reads from the input channel (or file if specified) and returns all lines that match a specific regex (regular expression).

In this case the regex is `M?Hz` which means, all lines containing (M)Hz.

Note you can drop the `M?` since it is optional: any line matching `MHz` will also match `Hz`...

Furthermore it depends what information you need: `/proc/cpuinfo` is probably the most extended list of CPU info. As @JonathanReinhart shows, `lscpu` is also a good candidate for more compact info.

In case the input is generated by a command, you can use a *pipe* (`|`):

```
command | grep 'Hz'
```

for instance:

```
lscpu | grep 'Hz'
```

A *pipe* means you use the *output* of the first `command` as *input* for the second command (here `grep`). By using a cascade of pipes, one can thus extract useful information, modify it, etc. You can compare this with an assembly line where the first program (worker) puts something on the assembly line, that is received and further processed by the second worker/program until it reaches the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you. Just from reading that post I have gained what I needed and more. Appreciate the help.